# How do you create a list of Observables in RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, reactivex

I've a API which gives me a list of ids. I need to use these ids to make another network request to get their details of individual items. Once I get all the details I need to put them in a list.

So here is an example. Make a network request, get a list of ids say

1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Now I need to make 5 separate requests for these 5 ids.

And then once I get the response of all, I need to create a list which is used to populate the RecyclerView.

Let me know if further information are needed. I'm new to Reactive programming.

Comment: What should the resulting list contain? Could you please provide some code (Data-classes)?

Answer (score 2):

Let us say that you have an observable source:

```
Observable<Integer> source;
```

You want to do a network request for each ID:

```
Long getLongFromIdViaNetwork(Integer id);
```

You compose them like so:

```
source
  .flatMap( i -> Observable.fromCallable( id -> getLongFromIdViaNetwork( id ) ) )
  .toList()
  .subscribeOn( backgroundScheduler )
  .observeOn( foregroundScheduler )
  .subscribe( listOfLongs -> {} );
```

where `backgroundScheduler` and `foregroundScheduler` are appropriate for our environment.

Answer (score 1):

The observable chain will have approximately the following structure:

- initial network request
- extract list from results
- fromIterable
- concatMapEager <- to ensure that the list of the results is the same as in the list.

  - the second network request
  - response extraction from the request
- toList

Answer (score 1):

If you want to receive only 1 emission that contains a List: use `Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);`

If you want to receive 5 emissions that contains a single number for each: use `Observable.from(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);`

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode: *Observable.from(listOfIds).flatMap(return request(id)).toList()*